# Global namespaces in XAML code generator

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Currently I am developing a library that contains namespaces like this: `Namespace1.Namspace2.Namespace3`. In my application framework user controls I also use another library which has namespace declarations the following way: `XXX.YYY.Namespace1.Namspace2.ZZZ`

When I am subclassing my user control from a control in my library  the VisualStudio compiler complains that `XXX.YYY.Namespace1.Namspace2` does not contain `Namespace1.Namspace2.Namespace3`.

So how can I set the compiler to reference my library's namespace globally like

```
public partial class MyControlClass : global::Namespace1.Namspace2.Namespace3.ControlBaseClass
```

instead of

```
public partial class MyControlClass : Namespace1.Namspace2.Namespace3.ControlBaseClass
```

when it is generating the code-behind files.

---

Luckily I could change the namespaces of my library but I wonder if there is any other solution to this problem.